# How to do state restoration in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-restoration

I made an Expense Tracker app which has a List named '_registeredExpenses'. This list stores all the expenses to be displayed when the app is opened . Now my problem is that when i kill the app , it doesnot store the added values or the deleted values . It just reverts back to its original state (original state has two hardcoded rows i.e handwash and cinema).

i tried to implement state restoration by extending the class RestorationMixin and then following the approach given in this video :https://youtu.be/5-u5VjPJsNI

Now my problem is that i wanted to convert the List named '_registeredExpenses' to a type of Restorable property so that it could be recieved as property argument by the registerForRestoration method (as is the approach given in the youtube video) , But so far all i get is  error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf6jp.png)

it is saying this :

The argument type 'List<Expense>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RestorableProperty<Object?>'.dart [argument_type_not_assignable](https://dart.dev/diagnostics/argument_type_not_assignable)

below are two images from my app:
First pic shows the state after adding an expense titled 'Milk' and before kiling the app.

Second pic shows the state after kiling the app and restarting it.

[image]
[image]

I got the app to run by commenting out the error area( So that i could show what i am talking about ).

below is my code snippet where I implemented the RestorationMixin :

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/main.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/chart/chart.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/new_expense.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/models/expense.dart';
import 'package:expense_tracker/widgets/expenses_list/expenses_list.dart';


class Expenses extends StatefulWidget {
  const Expenses({super.key});
  @override
  State<Expenses> createState() {
    return _ExpensesState();
  }
}

class _ExpensesState extends State<Expenses> with RestorationMixin {
  final List<Expense> _registeredExpenses = [
    Expense(
      title: 'Handwash',
      amount: 19.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      category: Category.hygiene,
    ),
    Expense(
      title: 'Cinema',
      amount: 150.69,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      category: Category.leisure,
    ),
  ];

  void _openAddExpenseOverlay() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled:
            true, //this ensures that the overlay takes full space available
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) {
          return NewExpense(onAddExpense: _addExpense);
        });
  }

  void _addExpense(Expense expense) {
    setState(() {
      _registeredExpenses.add(expense);
    });
  }

  void _removeExpense(Expense expense) {
    final expenseIndex = _registeredExpenses.indexOf(expense);
    setState(() {
      _registeredExpenses.remove(expense);
    });
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .clearSnackBars(); //clears any info message of prior deletions
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      content: const Text("Expense deleted"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        textColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        label: "Undo",
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            // if undo pressed , insert the expense back
            _registeredExpenses.insert(expenseIndex, expense);
          });
        },
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget mainContent = const Center(
      child: Text("No expenses found. Kindly start adding. "),
    );

    if (_registeredExpenses.isNotEmpty) {
      mainContent = ExpensesList(
        expenses: _registeredExpenses,
        onRemoveExpense: _removeExpense,
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        title: const Text("e-KHATA"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: _openAddExpenseOverlay,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.add_rounded,
                //color: Colors.deepOrange,
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Chart(expenses: _registeredExpenses),
          Expanded(child: mainContent)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  String? get restorationId => "RegdExpensesList";

  @override
  void restoreState(RestorationBucket? oldBucket, bool initialRestore) {
    registerForRestoration(_registeredExpenses, "RegD_Expenses");
  }
}
```

The error is Coming in the registerForRestoration method inside the restoreState method .

Please guide me . I am new to flutter . I have tried a lot but i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom restorable for your data type:
Checkout this code example https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorableValue-class.html

Although I would reccomend keeping the state persisted somewhere else. Checkout Riverpod and it's StateProvider for an extremely easy solution.

Comment: I tried doing so and writing the four overrides thereby created but still it doesn't seem to work .